# How may bytes / record in a VPC Flow Log?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am looking into the size difference between the 3 flavors of Flow Logs from Google, Amazon and Azure. I am specifically looking at the bytes per record.

How may bytes per record in a Google VPC Flow Log?

Comment: there are number of fields that can be variable in size, on top of that there is an option to include or exclude an additional metadata info.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to estimate the log size of a subnetwork. It is explained in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs#viewing_estimated_log_volume_for_existing_subnets) but every single log entry depends on whether you enable metadata annotations.

There are some samples on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/flow-logs).

Nevertheless, I would suggest trying each flow log behaviour from those flavours to have a good background of what you get from each one.